How do you use Storage::fake to make a fake storage_path() for phpunit
I am working on a Laravel site that utilizes local storage to store daily summary files, essentially log files filled with JSON. The folder I am saving is in the storage/history directory, which many of my functions access via storage_path('history'). I am writing PHPUnit tests for the functions involved in this process, including a function that deletes all files in this summary file folder. I want to avoid deleting the files in my real storage/history folder, so I have been exploring ways to instruct Laravel to use a different folder for these operations. Storage::fake(...) appears to be the solution I need. However, despite several attempts to implement it, I am yet to find the correct approach.

Storage::fake(storage_path()); gives me the following error:

League\Flysystem\UnableToCreateDirectory: Unable to create a directory at C:\xxx\yyy\storage\framework/testing/disks/C:\xxx\yyy\storage.


Storage::fake('storage'); Fails because the test deletes the real files.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here.  How do I fake the storage_path() folder for testing?

You have to use Storage::fake('DISK NAME TO FAKE'); in your case Storage::fake('history'); if history is a disk, else you have to write the disk you want to fake, check the official documentation about it

Btw make the disk “history” in filesystem.php and access thought Storage::disk(“history”) - it be more readable and flexible.

Mock the file operation part instead of storage_path().
Storage::fake() is not relevant.
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$file = storage_path('history/test.log');

File::delete($file);

tests
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

File::shouldReceive('delete')->once();

Another way
Add history disk.
// config/filesystems.php

    'disks' => [

        'history' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('history'),
        ],

Usage
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('history')->put('test.log', 'test');

Storage::disk('history')->delete('test.log');

tests
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::fake('history');

...

Storage::disk('history')->assertMissing('test.log');


it is exactly the opposite, follow laravel conventions, follow the community, use Storage:: not File::, so it is super relevant

Do you need to create a mockery of File before calling shouldReceive or not?

Answer: You do not need to creat a mockery first.  Laravel Facades include the shouldReceive() method.
